# How can I dynamically set the span size of an Item from a recyclerView with GridLayoutManager?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, grid-layout, gridlayoutmanager

I'm trying to show six items in a Recycler View using GridLayoutManager with span row count equals 2.
But when I have a single item on a row, I want his width to be match parent (to cover the entire row) but when a new Item is added, I want that new item to be on the same row with the previous and have 2 items on a single row. Is that possible?

This is my code:

**MainActivity**

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
private var arrayList: ArrayList<ItemModel>? = null
private var arrayListView: ArrayList<ItemModel>? = null
private var recyclerAdapter: RecyclerAdapter? = null
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    arrayList = setDataInList()
    arrayListView = ArrayList()
    val gridLayoutManager = GridLayoutManager(this, 2)
    gridLayoutManager.spanSizeLookup = object : GridLayoutManager.SpanSizeLookup() {
        override fun getSpanSize(position: Int): Int {
            Log.i("RAZ", position.toString())
            return when (position) {
                0 -> 2
                0, 1 -> 1
                else -> 1
            }
        }
    }
    my_recycler_view.layoutManager = gridLayoutManager

    my_recycler_view.setHasFixedSize(true)
    recyclerAdapter = RecyclerAdapter(applicationContext, arrayListView!!)
    my_recycler_view.adapter = recyclerAdapter

    var i = 0
    add_button.setOnClickListener {
        if (i < arrayList!!.size) {
            my_recycler_view.adapter?.notifyDataSetChanged()
            arrayListView!!.add(arrayList!![i])
            i++
            my_recycler_view.adapter?.notifyItemInserted(i)
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "No more items accepted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                .show()
        }
    }

   
    remove_button.setOnClickListener {
        if (arrayListView!!.size > 0) {
            if (i > 0) {
                arrayListView!!.removeLast()
                i--
                my_recycler_view.adapter?.notifyItemRemoved(arrayListView!!.size)
            }
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "No items available", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
    }
}
```

**RecyclerAdapter**

```
class RecyclerAdapter(var context: Context, var array: ArrayList<ItemModel>) : RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerAdapter.ItemHolder>() {
override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int):ItemHolder {

    val itemHolder = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.grid_layout_list_item, parent, false)
    return ItemHolder(itemHolder)
}

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ItemHolder, position: Int) {
     var item : ItemModel = array[position]

    holder.icons.setImageResource(item.itemImg!!)
    holder.itemText.text = item.itemText
    holder.itemView.setOnClickListener{
        Toast.makeText(context, item.itemText, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }
}

override fun getItemCount(): Int {
    return array.size
}

class ItemHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView){
    var icons : ImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_icon)
    var itemText : TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_text)
}
```

}

And this is how it looks right now. When I have only screen 1, I want it to be like in this picture, but when I add a new screen, I want it to be on the same row with screen 1 and so on.

[Click here to see the example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rHMTg.png)

Comment: try using StaggeredGridlayout  instead of grid view

Comment: can you show me an example of the implementation for this? Thanks!

Comment: https://trinitytuts.com/create-android-staggered-gridview-using-recyclerview/